# How can we manage and organise our "broken screen" questions?

Tags: discussion

We have a lot of questions on the [broken-screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-screen) tag, and they're all pretty similar but different. There are basically *n* variables, and you get a slightly different set of possible answers for each combination:-

- only the display is broken, or only the touchscreen is broken, or they're both broken
- USB debugging is already on or not
- an Android version where you have to click a notification to allow MTP, or an older version
- the user wants a full backup or just some files (just contacts, just SMSes)
- device supports [usb-on-the-go](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-on-the-go) or not
- full-device encryption or SD card encryption or neither

There's also a set of solutions, each of which is applicable to some subset of the situations. It makes it really hard for visitors to know where to look to find the answer to their question, and just as hard for us to triage new questions, determine if they're duplicates, and if so of which question.

How can we make this situation better? I'd like to get to a situation where it's easy to identify a list of possible solutions that are applicable to a given combination of factors, and to point visitors at that list.

Comment: Related: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1860/12442 . I think the problem is (now) bigger than simply having one canonical question, though.

Comment: Maybe one question but several answers?  Or several questions with one that links to all of them?

Comment: I though it's about shattered screen with cracks (but otherwise working).

Comment: Maybe a flowchart depiction (if it can be done ) to represent various possibilities and link suitable answers to decision flow outcomes?

Comment: We need a proper wiki page for it. AFAIK, there isn't one.